# Can I use my phone as a WiFi-WiFi hotspot?

Tags: applications, wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering, wifi-direct

I have a (non-rooted) Sony Xperia Z3 with default Lollipop installed. One challenge I often run into is that I can connect to a WiFi network, and my friends with iPhone cannot (I've also encountered the opposite, but that's another topic). It seems the hotspot functionality only works with connection to a telephone network, and not as a regular WiFi-WiFi hotspot. Do any of you know of a built in functionality that will do this, or an app I can download that will solve this issue for me? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes there is one app of late that does the job: see this post  https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173875/what-is-the-functionality-concept-behind-wi-fi-sharing-aka-wi-fi-profile-share

Comment: Definitely interesting. Thanks for sharing and for necromancing this thread :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't, at least with today's hardware standard. To be able to do that (connecting to a WiFi and tether that through WiFi again), you would need two WiFi beacons on your phone. Since this is not the case, it is not possible to do so.

Comment: But it would be possible to tether using Bluetooth or NFC (or even USB) between the mobile devices? And use the handset with connection to the WiFi as a router?

Comment: Using wifi for the connection and tether it using Bluetooth or USB is possible.

Comment: That is interesting. However, this wasn't intended as a yes/no question :) Do you know of any specific apps that can do this?